# Programmatically uploading files to Drupal, filesystem set to private

Tags: drupal, file, upload

I'm trying to use this script to upload files into Drupal. I'm having problems moving the file(s) from A to B. Drupal's filesystem is set to private

The nodes are created fine and everything works except for some reason I cannot download the attached file. It just takes me to page not found. If I create the node within drupal and upload the file it works fine.

I must be doing something wrong with my code here. I was following [this guide](http://drupal.org/node/330421) for uploading files but I can't seem to find anything about setting Drupal's file-system to private and what someone would have to do to make it work properly programmatically.

Anyone have any experience with this?

```
//prep file source and destination vars
$withoutExt = substr($file2, 0, -7);
$sourcePDF = "/var/www/html/pay.***.com/burst_pdfs/pdfs/" . $withoutExt . ".pdf";
$destinationPDF = '/var/paystubs/' . $drupalUid . '/' . $withoutExt . '.pdf';
$destination = '/var/paystubs/' . $drupalUid . '/';

//if the file does not exist, create it
if (!file_check_directory($destination, TRUE)){
    echo "Fail";    
}

// Copy the file to the Drupal files directory if it exists
if (file_exists($sourcePDF)) {

    if(!file_move($sourcePDF, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME)) {
        echo "Failed to move file: $sourcePDF.\n";
    } 
} else {

    echo "File Moved to " . $destination . "<br/>"; }


$mime = 'application/pdf'; // Importing PDF files
$file = new stdClass();
$file->filename = $withoutExt;
$file->filepath = $destinationPDF;
$file->filemime = $mime;
$file->filesize = filesize($destinationPDF);

$file->uid = 1;
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file->timestamp = time();
drupal_write_record('files', $file);       



$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = $employeeDate;
$node->body = $employeeID;
$node->type = 'estub';
$node->uid = 1;

//$field = field_file_save_file($file_drupal_path, file_directory_path() .'/'.    $directory);
//$node->$field_paystub_upload[] = $field;

$node->field_estub_upload = array(
    array(
      'fid' => $file->fid,
      'title' => basename($file->filename),
      'filename' => $file->filename,
      'filepath' => $file->filepath,
      'filesize' => $file->filesize,
      'mimetype' => $mime,
      'data' => array(
        'description' => $withoutExt,
      ),
      'list' => 1,
    ),
  );

  $node->status = 1;
  $node->active = 1;
  $node->promote = 1;
  node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the file needs to be in the "files" directory for drupal to have access to it. Is `/var/paystubs/$uid` what the is set as the "files" directory in Drupal? When you upload files using the interface do they end up in `/var/paystubs/$uid`

Comment: Yeah they end up there. I'm using a db query to find the users uid.

Comment: when you do your test, using the interface and the code are the files in the file system (including permissions), the rows in the files table and the devel output for the nodes identical? My next guess would be permissions in the file system.

Comment: Ok, the files are not being linked to correctly when the node is created.

Comment: herm. . . I'm guessing it's because you don't have a fid to put into the $node you are saving. I would look at the submit and nodeapi functions the module you are using and see how it's being done there.

Comment: im creating a new node with a newly attached file. i have to also make sure that the directory is created and do so automatically if its not. wouldnt it generate a fid automatically for a new file?

Comment: fid is generated, but there is no unique key linking the file to the node. . . I'm guessing. would need to look at the code for this module. to me it seams a little weird that the file is created before the node, seams like it should be the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, I'm just using the CCK FileField module. Maybe try switching the order of node creation? So, create and save the node then add the file to the node?

Comment: I had misunderstood, and thought you were using some other module becides file field.

Comment: I would look at how how file field handles uploads, and you might also review how the feeds module imports images for some different ways that may work. Since you approach isn't work you might look at using nodeapi to set the values you need, which may also work. However I'm just guessing.